# Python: return the misspelled word from a pdf

Tags: python, extract

I'm searching for words that exists in a specific list and i need to compare all the words in my file with each word in the list, when it finds an incorrect word, the program must print it
Here's the code:

- tokenised_word : the tokens from the file

```py
word_list = ["Curriculum vitae", "Expériences", "Formations", "Etudes", "Activités extraprofessionnelles", "Compétences", "Langage", "Certifications", "Tâches", "Centres d’intérêt"]
      
for word in word_list:
    for chaine in tokenised_word:
        if not word in chaine:
            print (word)
```

Comment: What is your output with this code?

Comment: What are the tokes you imported from the file?

Comment: @albert all the tokens in the file (it's a CV)

Comment: @Seppeke this code print all the tokens that not exist in the list .
I want just to compare the words in the list

Comment: Basically this can be done with: `words_not_in_list = [word for word in all_words if not word in word_list]`

Comment: for example in my file i have some incorrect words like "Foramtion" when the program compares it to the list of words it will defines it as an incorrect word so he will print  "foramtion"

Comment: So you want to find misspellings of specific words? The words you want to check (with correct spelling) and find the misspellings from the text are given in a list?

Comment: @albert yes exactly

Comment: A simple list comprehension or search would require a list with all possible misspellings of each word. Since this is not feasible and quite useless, you will need to think about more complex approaches. A Google search on `python spell checker` should give you some hints...